# Error: "Cannot find module 'semver' " when I call npm

Tags: node.js, npm, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8, and when I try to run `npm install && npm run dev`, this happen every time

```
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:772:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:816:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
    '/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

I've already tried force uninstall and install npm, but didn't work

Comment: try `npm install semver`

Comment: Same thing @MedetTleukabiluly, I try to install and apears same message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just work normal now, I literaly change the folder, come back and works fine.

In the other folder, I've used `npm -v` and works normally, when I back to the project folder, works normally